# How to display Postgres version in the CLI pompt?

Tags: postgresql, client

I whish to display the version of the server I am connected to in the command-line (console) interface prompt. From what I read in the documentation, it is possible to execute a shell command, it is possible to display a psql variable value.

The idea is to get the server's version information on connection and use it in the client's prompt. How can I (in the `.psqlrc` file ?) assign the server version in a psql variable ?

Edit: Jack Douglas♦ has the right answer by pointing out the `\gset` feature. It ended up with a

```
show server_version
\gset
\set PROMPT1 '%:server_version: >'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since 9.3, you can do this using \gset in psqlrc:

```
select split_part(version(),' ',2) pmt
\gset
\set PROMPT1 '%:pmt:'
```

Or, as '[the value of the selected prompt variable is printed literally, except where a percent sign (%) is encountered](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING)':

```
select split_part(version(),' ',2) "PROMPT1"
\gset
```

If your version is <9.3, it's [still possible, but much uglier](http://www.depesz.com/2013/02/03/waiting-for-9-3-create-a-psql-command-gset-to-store-query-results-into-psql-variables/), e.g. something like:

```
\set PROMPT1 `psql postgres postgres -Atc "select split_part(version(),' ',2)"`
```